# How do I rotate text in css?

Tags: css, text-rotation

How do I rotate text in CSS to get following output:

[image]

The problem I am facing is that when we rotate the text then it breaks the alignment and positions. So what is causing that, and how can I manage them?

HTML:

```
<div class="mainWrapper">
    <div class="rotateObj">
        <div class="title active">First Text Title</div>
        <div class="content">
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
        </div>
        <div class="title">First Text Title</div>
        <div class="content hide">
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
        </div>
        <div class="title">First Text Title</div>
        <div class="content hide">
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
        </div>
        <div class="title">First Text Title</div>
        <div class="content hide">
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
        </div>
        <div class="title">First Text Title</div>
        <div class="content hide">
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
            Here goes my bla bla bla text and more stuffs...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .mainWrapper{margin:0 auto; width:960px; background:#EFEFEF;}
    .rotateObj{position:relative; height:400px;}
    .rotateObj .title{
        float:left;
        background:gray;
        width:50px;
        height:100%;
        
        /** Rounded Border */ 
        border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;
        
        /** Rotation */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);    
        transform:rotate(-90deg);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    }
    .rotateObj .active{background:green;}
    .rotateObj .content{float:left;width:600px;height:100%;padding:20px;}
    .hide{display:none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/koolkabin/yawYM/

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to use the CSS3 [transform property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-property) `rotate` - [see here](http://caniuse.com/#search=rotate) for which browsers support it and the prefix you need to use.

One example for webkit browsers is `-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);`

**Edit:** The question was changed substantially so I have added a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6wSAJ/) that works in Chrome/Safari (as I only included the `-webkit-` CSS prefixed rules). The problem you have is that you do not want to rotate the *title div*, but simply the text inside it. If you remove your rotation, the `<div>`s are in the correct position and all you need to do is wrap the text in an element and rotate that instead.

There already exists a more customisable widget as part of the jQuery UI - see the [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) demo page. I am sure with some CSS cleverness you should be able to make the accordion vertical and also rotate the title text :-)

**Edit 2:** I had anticipated the text center problem and have already [updated my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6wSAJ/2/). There is a height/width constraint though, so longer text could still break the layout.

**Edit 3:** <strike>It looks like the horizontal version was part of the [original plan](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137702/Accordion) but I cannot see any way of configuring it on the demo page.</strike> I was incorrect… the new accordion is part of the **upcoming** jQuery UI 1.9! So you could try the development builds if you want the new functionality.

Hope this helps!

Comment: m having problem with position of the rotated text

Comment: hm... checked your fiddle... its resulting good. but i test with some extra text and got title not aligning center to the container. trying "Long text on first line" instead of "first line"

Comment: I have updated the demo to use the CSS3 [transform-origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-origin-property) and to center the titles. You could still use the `position:relative` parent, `position:absolute` child trick to move the text if `transform-origin` is not well supported cross-browser.

Comment: but wondering how are those css transformation orgini value calculated: `84px 70px;`

Comment: about jqueryui accordian is there vertical or horizontal whatever similar to this one too?

Comment: @KoolKabin: the values were chosen to be a _virtual_ center point of a circle in which to rotate the text around. In the fiddle you can imagine that point in the middle of the word _incididunt_. If you inspect the `<span>` in Chrome developer tools and then change the rotation angle you should be able to _see_ where the point is. I just chose the point that gave the best result. There is certainly a mathematical answer to it but I was being quick :-)

Comment: Searching for jquery horizontal accordion, I found http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion to have a nice demo, however the vertical text is accomplished with images and not CSS rotation.

Answer (score 93):

In your case, it's the best to use rotate option from transform property as mentioned before. There is also `writing-mode` property and it works like rotate(90deg) so in your case, it should be rotated after it's applied. Even it's not the right solution in this case but you should be aware of this property.

Example:

```
writing-mode:vertical-rl;
```

More about transform: https://kolosek.com/css-transform/

More about writing-mode: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/writing-mode/

Comment: **This is by far the better answer as it rotates the text without side effects**, eg, add a background to the text and see how transforming the entire element rotates that too.

Comment: This works great. And, if you want the text to face to the "right" (tops of letters to left), use "writing-mode: vertical-lr;transform: rotate(-180deg);" which gets the spacing and orientation.

Comment: @AndrewPhilips Keeping `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` works best when combined with `transform`, as it makes multiline text read normally.  If you use `vertical-lr` then each line of text appears above the last rather than below it (or to the left of it once rotated, rather than to the right as you'd expect).

Comment: @Malvineous good point. Guessing I was only considering one line. However, with multi line `-rl` and `transform` layers the lines in the expected reading order.

Answer (score 21):

I guess [this](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation) is what you are looking for?

Added an example:

The html:

```
<div class="example-date">
  <span class="day">31</span> 
  <span class="month">July</span> 
  <span class="year">2009</span>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.year
{
    display:block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); //For IE support
}
```

Alle examples are from the mentioned site.

Comment: +1 and also hurrays for adding the examples and not just a link.

Comment: m having problem with position of the rotated text

Comment: @KoolKabin, is your fiddle the latest version?

Comment: yeah it is...the latest one... m testing its next version on my local

Answer (score 15):

Using `writing-mode` and `transform`.

```
.rotate {
     writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
}


<span class="rotate">Hello</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use like this...

```
<div id="rot">hello</div>

#rot
{
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
   -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);    
    width:100px;
}
```

Have a look at this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/anish/MAN4g/

Comment: m having problem with position of the rotated text

Answer (score 2):

[image]

also you can

```
<div style="position:relative;display:block; height:125px;width:300px;">
    <div class="status">
        <div class="inner-point">
            <div class="inner nowrap">
                Some text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.status {
    position: absolute;
    background: #009FE3;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 37px;
}

.status .inner-point {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
    width: 37px;
    height: 37px;
}

.status .inner {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 27px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    color: white;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use transform: rotate(0.5turn);

Answer (score 0):

```css
     h5 {    
            transform: matrix(0,-1,1,0,-9,-18);
            white-space:nowrap;
            display:block;
            bottom:0;
            width:20px;
            height:20px;
            margin: 0;
     }
     div {
     padding-top:70px;
     }
```

```html
<div>
<h5>Hello World</h5>
</div>
```

start writing from bottom, from left to right, this working for both image and text

or using rotate, turn

```css
     h5 {    
            transform: rotate(-1.250turn);
            white-space:nowrap;
            display:block;
            bottom:0;
            width:20px;
            height:20px;
            margin: 0;
     }
     div {
     padding-top:70px;
     }
```

```html
<div>
<h5>Hello World</h5>
</div>
```