# Rotated text behaves strange

Tags: html, css

I'd like to achieve the following:[image]

but it's bleeding from several wounds:

- Can't close `#div1` to top.
- Can't give dinamic size (%) value to `#div2`, so like `h3` and `h4`

What I can do so far:
http://jsbin.com/ivemal/30/

The html code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div id="div1"> 
      <h3> Title </h3>
      <h4> SubTitle </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="div2"> 
      ...
    </div>
  </li>
  <li> 
    ...Same...
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I think the root cause I can't achieve this, is the rotated text. Can someone guide me, how to handle this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028128/how-do-i-rotate-text-in-css

Comment: What do you mean by "Can't give dinamic (%) value to #div2"?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it. I meant size (width, height).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"> <div>
        <h3>text</h3>
        <h4>text2</h4>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id="inner2">Other text...</div>
</div>
```

I changed the `span` to a `div` because technically you cannot have block-level elements (i.e. headings) within a `span`.

## CSS

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
#outer {
    background: green;
}
#inner {
    background:#e3e3e3;
    height:100px;
    width:50px;
    float: left;
}
#inner > div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    line-height: 0;
}

#inner2 {
    margin-left:70px;
    background:#e3e3e3;
}
#inner2::after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Axaw5/).

Comment: Thanks. If I put spaces in `<h3>` and `<h4>` then its not adjusting the size of them and puts all words in the same place.
http://jsfiddle.net/Axaw5/1/

Comment: The `<h3>` and `<h4>` problem solved with `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but is this what you want to obtain?

http://jsbin.com/ivemal/38/

Comment: Thanks, but it has the same problem as @rink.attendant.6 's answers. Try to put more text in the rotated text. It will put all text on top of each other. + It's drops the text in `#div1` under `#div2` if it's too long. http://jsbin.com/ivemal/39/