# Alignment of rotated text

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, text-rotation

I'm facing a problem of rotating text vertically. I've already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028128/how-do-i-rotate-text-in-css) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489775/rotated-text-behaves-strange?lq=1), but still couldn't adjust my snippet to work properly.

i'm trying to achieve vertical text to be align at the center and equal heights for both divs.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="vertical">
    <span class="vertical-text">short title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="horizontal">
     long text
  </div>
</div>
```

and current css:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-table;
}
.vertical {
  display: table-cell;
}
.vertical-text {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.horizontal { display: table-cell; }
```

Here's the link to a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kq9lElkmixEpTVRFxXZx?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

You can add to `.vertical` css class this line:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

it will align you text vertically.

---

So your class should be like this:

```
.vertical {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas how to adjust width of the first div now?