# Rotate html special character or text

Tags: html, css

I have this html character:

```
<div class="rotate">&#62;&#62;</div>
```

I want this character facing down, for example.

I found this css, it seems not working.

```
.rotate{
webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

how to rotate?
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzawLfgz/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i rotate text in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028128/how-do-i-rotate-text-in-css)

Comment: Ancient typo question, voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to rotate a `span` instead you need to change its `display` property.

```css
.rotate-span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(18deg);
}

.rotate-div {
  transform: rotate(-18deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate-div">&#62;&#62;</div>
<span class="rotate-span">&#62;&#62;</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);` by`-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);` there was typo you missed `-`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pzawLfgz/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
.rotate{
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pzawLfgz/2/

and notice this:

> It is important that after the special imagined to for old browser
>   versions CSS commands generally comes last. This then the browser
>   always delivers the last recognized command and the broadly defined is
>   better than anything that can even slightly differ in their
>   implementation. Therefore, please always structured as follows: from
>   the particular to the general

Comment: @TheMiniJohn The order of the properties is different.

Comment: Fixed webkit type and provided standard property as well so this seems to be a correct answer

Comment: It doesn't seem to work cross-browsers unless you set the element display to 'inline-block'.