# How to rotate some text in html css?

Tags: html, css

I want to do something like this. 
[image]

I dont know the property of css should be used.
my code is:

```
<h1><b>#GIRLBOSSES</b></h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 b {
    position: absolute; 
    color: #fdd2e9; 
    margin-left: 127px; 
    margin-top: 191px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i rotate text in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028128/how-do-i-rotate-text-in-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Test live](https://jsfiddle.net/2q5uj54L/)**

```
h1 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-9deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-9deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-9deg);
}
```

Edit: In the title of the post you asked about vertical text. For vertical, set it to `-90`.

Answer (score 3):

You need several settings. Different for different browsers.

```
.rotate {
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(7deg);
}
```

Look in JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/z5dcnrwa/

Answer (score 3):

you can use css transform to do that

```
h1{
    transform: rotate(-18deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [CSS3 transform Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).  In your case, it would look something like this:

`<h1 style="position: absolute; color: #fdd2e9; margin-left: 127px; margin-top: 191px; -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg); transform: rotate(-7deg);"><b>#GIRLBOSSES</b></h1>`

The operative styles are:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(-7deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(-7deg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

```css
.tilted {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fdd2e9;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10%;
  font-size:50px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
  <h1 class="tilted"><b>#GIRLBOSSES</b></h1>
</div>
```